# Existe algum jeito de fazer um "git pull" sem conflitos?

Tags: git

Depois  de muito na vida de programação quebrar a cabeça fazendo FTP para atualizar o sistema que está rodando em produção, eu resolvi adotar como padrão a utilização do `GIT`.

Quando tenho uma nova atualização testada, eu faço um `git pull` no diretório da aplicação em produção. Fica mais fácil assim, e o que eu faria com 20 minutos ou mais faço com 2 segundos.

Porém surgiu uma preocupação: E se quando eu der um `git pull`, der o famoso "Conflito de merge" nos arquivos?

Comecei a pesquisar na internet se haveria alguma forma de fazer um `git pull`, forçando a modificar os arquivos para a última atualização, sem ter problemas de "merge conflicts", mas não achei muita coisa (talvez por não saber o que pesquisar em inglês).

Não sei se isso é relevante, mas obviamente, os arquivos em produção não são alterados. Mesmo assim, não se poderia ocorrer um conflito justamente em produção.

Alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer um `git pull`, porém sem dar conflitos? É possível isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você sempre usar `git pull` e não fizer nenhuma alteração no repositório, não vai dar conflito; pois conflitos só podem ocorrem se o `git` não conseguir fazer `merge` automático entre seu repositório local e o repositório remoto. Se você nunca tiver alterações locais, ele não precisa fazer merge.

Mas se esse problema ocorrer em outra ocasião, segue a resposta baseada em uma [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785107/resolve-conflicts-using-remote-changes-when-pulling-from-git-remote):

Se você for sempre descartar qualquer mudança que foi feita localmente, você não deve fazer `pull` - `pull` significa baixar os *commits* remotos e fazer merge.
Tudo que você precisa fazer é:

```
# obter o branch padrão remoto (origin)
git fetch
# resetar seu branch atual (master) para o master origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Então é alguém que anda fazendo khda e editando os arquivo em produção, heheheh. +1

Answer (score 2):

O Daniel respondeu bem, se não tiver modificações localmente, o `pull` irá ser feito sem problemas mas caso você tenha modificado algo, é preferível as modificações sejam salvas antes de fazer o `pull`:

- Salvando as modificações: `git stash save` ou `git stash`
- `git pull`
- Recuperando as modificações: `git stash apply` ou `git stash pop`